# Matplotlib legend fontsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

Am I using the fontsize argument incorrectly in the following code? 
According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend), this should be a valid keyword argument.

```
import pylab
pylab.plot(range(5), label='test')
pylab.legend(fontsize='small') 
pylab.show()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_label.py", line 6, in <module>
    pylab.legend(fontsize='small')
  File "C:\swframe\python-V01-01\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2
791, in legend
    ret =  gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\swframe\python-V01-01\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 447
5, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'
```

Python: 2.7, Matplotlib: 1.1.0

Edit: Note, I am not looking for alternative ways to set the font size. I want to know why this goes wrong.

Comment: With matplotlib version 1.3.0 I'v got no errors...

Comment: @GM erm, never mind.  The problem is I can't read.  (read it as 'which version? with 1.3 I've got no errors')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pylab.legend(prop={'fontsize': 'small'})
```

[1.2.0 `legend` docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) (the oldest I could find online)

Setting the font size via kwarg does not work because you are using an antiquated version of `matplotlib`.  The error it is giving you,  `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'` means that `fontsize` is not a valid keyword argument of the `__init__` function.

The functionality of passing in `fontsize` was added in [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/812) PR which was done between the 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 releases.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but if you see my question, it specifically says I don't need alternatives, just an explanation why this doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work: "NameError: name 'fontsize' is not defined"

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Added missing quotes.